# links become inactive when document is scrolled past a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote some JS to make a div have a sticky float effect like: http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html

However when I scroll past a certain point the links in the div become inactive one at a time from top to bottom.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="sticky-float">
    <h4 id="math">MATH</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="math/genstudies.html">General Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="math/business.html">Finanace &amp; Business</a></li>
        <li><a href="math/engineering.html">Engineering &amp; Technical</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h4>SCIENCE</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="science/prepphysics.html">Preparatory Physics</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h4>MARITIME</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="maritime/maritime.html#shipsuperintendentgeneral">Ship Superintendent (General)</a></li>
        <li><a href="maritime/maritime.html#shipsuperintendentmarine">Ship Superintendent (Marine)</a></li>
        <li><a href="maritime/maritime.html#shipsuperintendenttechnical">Ship Superintendent (Technical)</a></li>
        <li><a href="maritime/maritime.html#breakbulkshipping">Breakbulk Shipping</a></li>
        <li><a href="maritime/maritime.html#lngcargooperations">LNG Cargo Operations</a></li>
        <li><a href="maritime/maritime.html#maritimelogistics1">Maritime Logistics I</a></li>
        <li><a href="maritime/maritime.html#marineengineering">Marine Engineering</a></li>
        <li><a href="maritime/maritime.html#shipoperations">Ship Operations</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sticky-float{
    background-color: #a0cbda;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
}

#sticky-float,
#sticky-float h4{
    font-family: "FuturaStd-Book";
}

#sticky-float ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    right: 18px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $stickyYInit = $('#sticky-float').offset().top;
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var $documentY = $(document).scrollTop();
        var $stickyY = $('#sticky-float').offset().top;
        if($documentY+70 >= $stickyYInit){
            $('#sticky-float').css('top', (($documentY+70)-$stickyYInit) + "px");
        }
        if($documentY+50 < $stickyYInit){
            $('#sticky-float').css('top', 20 + "px");
        }
    });
});
```

Your help is much appreciated. I am at a loss here. Thank you all!!

Comment: do you have a link where I can see the issue?

Comment: My first guess is you have something overlaying ontop of your sticky DIV... my suggestions is when you the scroll gets to position where you want the sticky to stick.. give your div position:fixed and high z-index.. you don't need to keep setting it's offset.

Comment: @webkit i don't have a link yet...still waiting on FTP info from the client. I'll try your suggestion in the morning. Not a bad idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked perfectly with my, it looks that there is an **element** covering the **menu** in your website, so try to add `z-index` in your **CSS** so it will be like this:

### CSS

```
#sticky-float{
    background-color: #a0cbda;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Hope this will help you ...

---

Also it's much better if you use `position: fixed` in your **JavaScript** instead of `position: relative` , so try this :

### JavaScript

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    $("#sticky-float").css("top", Math.max(0, 20 - $(window).scrollTop()));
});
```

### CSS

```
#sticky-float{
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: @user2731260 I've updated my answer, and added some additional informations

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to do it

### JS

```
var $documentY, $sticky, $stickyY;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $sticky = $('#sticky-float');
    $stickyY = $sticky.offset().top;
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        $documentY = $(document).scrollTop();
        if ($documentY >= $stickyY && $sticky.hasClass('stick')) return;
        $sticky.attr('class', ($documentY >= $stickyY) ? "stick" : "");
    });
});
```

### css

```
.stick { position:fixed; top:20px; z-index:99; -webkit-transition:top 500ms ease; transition:top 500ms ease;}
```